# Convert a string to a component object in MIT App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I am building an app in MIT App Inventor. I have several textboxes. If I click on a textbox, the colorpicker screen opens and the user can choose a color. Like here:
[image]

The variable "component" (recognition of the clicked textbox) is parsed to the Screen and after the color was picked and button1 was clicked, the rgb value and the "component" is returned back to the previus screen.

[image]

The Screen is changed back and now the textbox should show the rgb value as a text in the box. Thats why the app need the information, which textbox called the color picker screen before.

[image]
The component is stored back as string, but it should be parsed as a textbox component, so the program is able to know, which textbox the RGB Value should be filled in.

com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.TextBox@7b920d1

Is there a solution to convert the string "com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.TextBox@7b920d1" to this format: com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.TextBox@7b920d1

Comment: in the first screenshot fix the red warning and fill the empty socket and rather than using several screens, use only one screen and arrangements as virtual screens to avoid the problem of switching and passing values from screen to screen, see also tip 1 [here](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/general-tips-and-tricks-for-app-inventor/122?u=taifun)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot. Especially, the tip with the eventhandler screen https://puravidaapps.com/manager.php was very useful for my app, too. I hope I will be able to compile the app, after the code is finished.